# trying to send a command list through serial port but only the first line is taken by the device others are ignored

Tags: bash, serial-port

I am trying to send a message including carriage returns (represented without pressing enter) over a serial connection. It works if i press enter with an open serial connection, but I have not found a way to represent the carriage return character successfully within the message body.
Need to represent the **"CR"** in txt file.

Commands are listed in text file. I’m using:

```
while read line ; do
  echo "$line" | picocom -b 115200 --omap crcrlf /dev/ttyACM0
done < file.txt
```

Note: the modem documentation say n order to successfully communicate with modem device, the “$WP” or “$wp” prefix is
required when issuing command and the **"CR"** is required for terminating the
command line.

Comment: The modem may stop processing a line with a carriage return CR , but the operating system probably uses newline (\n). Try using both

Comment: Same issue, it seem like the modem need to be deconnected after received a command line before taking another. I tried to send file with structure like:                             command line                                                                                                                       fuser -k /dev/ttyACM0                                                                                                      command line                                                                                                                         But shell exit n don't continued

Comment: I looks like you're invoking a new picocom for each line in your loop.  What happens if you just cat file.txt piped to your picocom command?

Comment: Already tried but same issue, only first line is took by modem.                                          cat p.txt | picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyACM0

Comment: How i could close filedescritor of the portserial and reopen it before sending next command ?

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded using minicom with script. 
It was necessary to consider answers sent by the modem to be able to proceed to the following command. What I managed to do with "expect" as following:

```
send <command>
expect "OK"
send <command>
expect "OK"
....
```

You can refer to minicom man page https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-runscript/